# How to fix start of Windows 7 after Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS instalation?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, windows-7

In GRAB:
1) Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/mmcblk0p1)
2) Window 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)

When I'm selecting 1-st:

error: no such device: B4FE-5315
the volume assigned equeal 0x83
error: invalid signature

When I'm selecting second item I getting 1 second of black screen and then coming back in grab menu.

I tried to use "Boot Repair" but it threw an error that I've booted in Legacy mode. But I got log =)
http://paste2.org/wZ9nme7Z

Sorry for my english, I'm not a magician yet)

Answer (score 0):

According to your Boot-Repair Log

> The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after
>   changing it to EFI mode.

You need to enter BIOS and change Boot Type from Legacy to UEFI.

Comment: My laptop have not this option (lenovo z370). Probably, I need to update my BIOS but I would like to fix boot without this step. Can I?

Comment: Your laptop has that option and it should be used for both OSes. However, Windows 7 has been installed in Legacy mode and Ubuntu appears to have been also installed in Legacy mode. So, the dual boot should work. Grub, the bootloader, cannot fix a non booting Windows.